# How to setup drupal multisite in cpanel?

Tags: 8, multi-sites

I want to setup a drupal multisite but without success. I have followed this tutorials (and search in drupal answer):
- [2 minutes multisite](https://www.drupal.org/node/960934)
- [5 minutes multisite](https://www.drupal.org/node/348619)
- [Setting up a multisite](https://www.kalose.net/oss/drupal-8-setting-multi-site/)
I have tried with subdomains and with alias. My first question is when I create the alias or subdomain in cPanel, should I create a redirec? Now, I've left it blank, but I'm not sure if I have to create a redirect.

I always get:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

or

> CGI-Error. Sorry. The page you request is not available.

I don't know what else I could do. Could some one detail me the steps? Thanks.

Comment: But can you setup a default site at all? If not then there might be something wrong with your server which needs to get fixed in the first place.

Comment: Yes. The main site is working good without any problem. I have created the new folders in sites for every subdomain, modified sites.php, and all the steps. But I doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. My settings.php file had redis configuration, and that was the problem. I found it because I added this line to settings.php file:

```
$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';
```